# How searching a million keys organized as B-tree will need 114 comparisons?

Tags: database, indexing, data-structures, tree, b-tree

Please explain how it will take 114 comparisons. The following is the screenshot taken from my book (Page 350, Data Structures Using C, 2nd Ed. Reema Thareja, Oxford Univ. Press). My reasoning is that in worst case each node will have just minimum number of children (i.e. 5), so I took log base 5 of a million, and it comes to 9. So assuming at each level of the tree we search minimum number of keys (i.e. 4), it comes to somewhere like 36 comparisons, nowhere near 114.

> Consider a situation in which we have to search an un-indexed and
> unsorted database that contains n key values. The worst case running
> time to perform this operation would be O(n). In contrast, if the data
> in the database is indexed with a B tree, the same search operation
> will run in O(log n). For example, searching for a single key on a set
> of one million keys will at most require 1,000,000 comparisons. But if
> the same data is indexed with a B tree of order 10, then only 114
> comparisons will be required in the worst case.

[Page 350, Data Structures Using C, 2nd Ed. Reema Thareja, Oxford Univ. Press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkgtY.jpg)

Comment: I'll come up with a solution soon, but for starters, try using a visualizer to understand how it's working for a smaller number of keys. It usually is a piece of cake once you understand it.

Comment: Thanks Aritro, but actually I am unable to grasp it even though I have sincerely finished all the theory related to it, like minimum number of keys in each node, properties of B trees etc. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: I am assuming the keys also have a value related with them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case tree has the minimum number of keys everywhere *except* on the path you're searching.

If the size of each internal node is in [5,10), then in the worst case, a tree with a million items will be about 10 levels deep, when most nodes have 5 keys.

The worst case path to a node, however, might have 10 keys in each node.  The statement seems to assume that you'll do a linear search instead of a binary search inside each node (I would advise to do a binary search instead), so that can lead to around 10*10 = 100 comparisons.

If you carefully consider the details, the real number might very well come out to 114.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt for taking the time to answer (I hadn't expected any answer, especially a good one from a contributor like you). It motivates maths noobs like me further :-)

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an Answer to the question asked, but a related discussion.)

Sounds like a textbook question, not a real-life question.

Counting comparisons is likely to be the best way to judge an in-memory tree, but not for a disk-based dataset.

Even so, the "average" number of comparisons (for in-memory) or disk hits (for disk-based) is likely to be the metric to compute.

(Sure, it is good to compute the maximum numbers as a useful exercise for understanding the structures.)

Perhaps the optimal "tree" for *in memory* searching is a Binary tree, but with 3-way fan out.  And keep the tree balanced with 2 or 3 elements in each node.

For *disk based* searching -- think databases -- the optimal is likely to be a BTree with the size of a block being based on what is efficient to read from disk.  Counting comparisons in a poor second when it comes to the overall time taken to fetch a row.